# Adding third party Library to the native project makes the "IBMMobilefirst Platform "not found?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I want to add "Crashlytics" and "Appsflyer" framework in the IBM Mobilefirst iOS Project.  After adding the Framework  it shows that the " **'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/MFPMainViewController.h' file not found".**
Tried with both Cocoapods and Framework, but getting the same error.
But its fine with native project.

Sample Project is available in 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8u54gfrmofqzhf/native.zip?dl=0

Please suggest how to resolve it.

[image: Before adding Crashlytics]
[image: After adding Crashlytics]

Comment: Can you please explain more around IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid and where does it stand in hierarchy or simple image with project structure etc...

Comment: Framework for both "Crashlytics" and "Appsflyer" is added. Once the framework is added the error rises.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Adding `"$(SRCROOT)/frameworks"` in your Frameworks Search Path under Build Settings of your Xcode Project, I hope it should resolve the issue.

Also i have added `Crashlytics` and `Appsflyer` in MFP 7.1 Hybrid Project and I did not find any issues. Sample application you can find [here](https://ibm.box.com/s/7mi13rcl903phi1vcrifrgqdyegien2u).